# My scrolling on site is not reaching the top?

Tags: html, css, browser, scroll

As the title says. Can't say much more.

[image: What is happening]

As you can see this occurs on both Chrome and Firefox.

webkit scroll bar, didn't work. Deactivated scroll bar.

Overflow: scroll

My code

I also need to add extra details. My issue occured after not many changes, it worked completely fine before I added a certain section (The button at bottom, with 'All Information'

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: Bluu;
    src: url(cdn/fonts/BluuNext-master/fonts/BluuNext-Bold.otf);
  }

  @font-face {
    font-family: Karrik;
    src: url(cdn/fonts/karrik_fonts-main/fonts/Web/TFF/Karrik-Regular.ttf);
  }

html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,
                                       left bottom,
                                       left top,
                                       color-stop(0.44, rgb(122,153,217)),
                                       color-stop(0.72, rgb(73,125,189)),
                                       color-stop(0.86, rgb(28,58,148)));
}

body {
    background-color: #64B6AC;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.content {
    background-color: #C0FDFB;
    max-width: 75%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    box-shadow: rgba(100, 100, 111, 0.2) 0px 7px 29px 0px;
}

.interior {
    margin-left: 40px;
}

.hamburger {
    font-size: 40px;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

/* General Styles for all */

.lower-area {
    margin-top: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.button-styles {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: rgba(100, 100, 111, 0.2) 0px 7px 29px 0px;
    font-family: Karrik;
    color: rgb(8, 8, 8);
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.button-styles:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: rgb(8, 8, 8);
}

/* Headings */

.large-heading {
    font-family: Bluu;
    font-size: 7vw;
}

.medium-heading {
    font-family: Bluu;
    font-size: 5vw;
}

.sub-heading {
    font-family: Karrik;
    font-size: 3vw;
}

/* Paragraphs */

.paragraph {
    font-size: 1.4vw;
    max-width: 90%;
    display: block;
    font-family: Karrik;
    font-weight: 200;
}

/* Mobile responsiveness */

@media (max-width:1000px)  {
    .content {
        min-width: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
    }

    .hamburger {
        font-size: 25px;
        margin-top: 40px;
    }

    .paragraph {
        font-size: 4vw;
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/9ab5d42652.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>KDGuide</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="interior">
            <div class="top-area">
                <a class="hamburger" href="/">&#9776;</a>
                <h1 class="large-heading">Welcome to CODE SNIPPET</h1>
                <h1 class="sub-heading">This is a code snippet</h1>
                <p class="paragraph">I am having an issue where I can not 
                scroll higher than a certain point.
                </p>
                <h1 style="text-align: center; ">
                    <a href="#alltutorials" class="large-heading" style="text-decoration: none; color: black;">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-down"></i>
                    </a>
                </h1>        
            </div>

            <div class="lower-area">
                <br>
                <h1 class="sub-heading" id="alltutorials">All Info</h1>
                <p class="paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent dignissim varius dolor et varius. Duis sit amet rhoncus eros, at consequat nisi. Donec sed finibus enim. Aenean rutrum odio vitae cursus bibendum. Maecenas pharetra libero lorem, sed maximus metus rhoncus.
                </p>
                <a href="/" class="button-styles">View</a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Hi there @mplungjan unfortunately the original gif I attached didn't work, please see new gif or go to https://s4.gifyu.com/images/ezgif.com-gif-makerb6e127a4fca6d364.gif !!!

Comment: We STILL need to see some code in a [mcve]

Comment: I've done it @mplungjan - run the code snippet. The code snippet shows the issue too for me

Comment: You need to reconsider the translate you use

Answer (score 1):

that is probably because of what you used to center your content.
You should consider using display flex to center your content in your body.

You used translate top with 50% which is not related to the height of your page

Comment: That works but it is now not horizontally central
I used `display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;`

Comment: I don't understand this new issue because when I do it I don't have to same issue...
You have to put display things in the body css

Comment: hmmm.. https://i.imgur.com/fXb08C7.png - my code
how it's coming out https://i.imgur.com/5Wh7oHO.png

Comment: Yep, align-item and justify-content should be in the body css too, that's not what you did ^^